# Google Chrome class attribute bug?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Any ideas, why `querySelector` works only with selector `#home_img` but not with `.navbarSprite` ?

[image]

URL: http://www.imdb.com

Context: download HTML source code from IMDB and put in into iframe.

Comment: What's the url? You aren't showing any markup or css here for anyone to help you with.

Comment: It's not about URL CSS or HTML. How is it possible, that `document.querySelector("a[class=navbarSprite]")` works, but `document.querySelector("a.navbarSprite")` doesn't ?

Comment: it matters because both of those work just fine. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YawZNj